# how to render a list of items but not the key

Tags: javascript, react-native

Currently the below code renders just fine
I get several TEXT components displaying text on the screen

I also get a warning though that says
`each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop`

```
renderAlertItem = (alerts) => {
        arr = []
        for (var x = 0; x < alerts.length-1; x++){ //the last item in the list is the add alert button so we can ignore it
            arr.push(
            <Text style={{color: colors.whiteText}} >
                Settings for the {alerts[x].alertname} alert
            </Text>
            )
        }
        return arr
    }

    render() {
        const alerts=this.props.alerts

        return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',}}>
            {this.renderAlertItem(alerts)}
        </View>
        );

    }
```

What's the best way to go about this?

doing this produces an error as the code is now returning a list of objects and not the list of `<Text>` components like it was before.

```
arr.push({key:x,item:
          <Text style={{color: colors.whiteText}} >
             Settings for the {alerts[x].alertname} alert
          </Text>
          })
```

NB: that `this.props.alerts` is an list of objects similar to this `[{key:1, alertname:name, alerttype:type, setting:30}]` and it already has its own `key` as part of the object. So could this be used somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
renderAlertItem = (alerts) => {
        arr = []
        for (var x = 0; x < alerts.length-1; x++){ //the last item in the list is the add alert button so we can ignore it
            arr.push(
            <Text style={{color: colors.whiteText}} key={x}>
                Settings for the {alerts[x].alertname} alert
            </Text>
            )
        }
        return arr
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should map your array to elements, and put the object key property right on the key prop of the element. Array::map creates a new array for you, and the slice(0, -1) gets all but the last array element. Here I have used object destructuring to extract the properties bring rendered, you can add `alerttype` later if needed.

```
renderAlertItem = alerts => alerts
  .slice(0,-1)
  .map(({ alertname, key }) => (
    <Text
      key={key}
      style={{color: colors.whiteText}}
    >
      Settings for the {alertname} alert
    </Text>
  ));
```